# Receive POST data inside angular component

Tags: angular, payment-gateway

I am integrating Payment gateway in Angular version 7.

Payment gateway needs data input like below

```
requestParameter : MerchantId||CollaboratorID||Encrypted_string
```

I tried to submit form using ngForm as below, but my request is not posting to Payment gateway url and getting error 404 not found for "http://localhost:4200/direcPayment/" and Session expired message of Payment gateway in a response of that. It's just like if anything is wrong in the request you get session expired message.

```
<form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" method="POST" mt-3>
```

Behind in the code, I am passing the parameter as required and making http.post call as below. On click of OnSubmit I have called formSubmit with encrypted string

```
formSubmit( encryptedString) {
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append( 'requestParameter', encryptedString);

this.http.post('direcPayment/', formData, httpFormDataOptions)
    .subscribe((resposne) => {
      console.log(resposne);
    });
```

}

Inside "httpFormDataOptions" I have added below headers

```
const httpFormDataOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders(),
};
httpFormDataOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
httpFormDataOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS');
httpFormDataOptions.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
```

/direcPayment refers to my Proxy.config.json file as below

```
{
  "/direcPayment": {
  "target": "PaymentGatewayURL",
  "secure": true,
  "pathRewrite": {"^/direcPayment" : ""},
  "changeOrigin": true
  },
}
```

so currently I used ngNoForm and submit the form using action attribute.

So I want to ask two queries

1. Submitting form to payment gateway link using httpClient POST method
2. Payment Gateway says, if payment is either successful/failure then they will redirect to success/failure URL as POST data in encrypted format, So how to receive data to a specific URL in angular? Is there any way to receive data if someone called my angular URL in both cases either using httpClient Call OR ngNoForm

Thanks.

Comment: Please use, https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
this.http.post('direcPayment/', formData, httpFormDataOptions)
    .subscribe((resposne) => {
      console.log(resposne);
    });
}
```

so the post data will be submitted to `http://localhost:4200/direcPayment/`, you should put the URL of your payment gateway here

Comment: Are you sure your payment gateway is working? Can you send requests to it using `curl` or `postman`?

Comment: Hi I tried your way and got similar link also https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qs5lm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpayment.service.ts , so here in the response I am getting direcPay page HTML. So I think PSP hosted gateway requires a URL redirection not API call, so I have done that also but payment gateway redirects back to angular, so how to handle this in angular. As angular is client side so we cannot handle incoming POST from extrenal URL, someone told me that we can mixup PHP inside angular and can receive POST data inside angular, but not sure how to do that, so trying and searching for same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a server-side) back-end for your application, you should probably handle the entire transaction from the back end.

If you don't have a back-end at all, I have no suggestions. I can't think of any secure way to do this entirely on the client side.

Comment: Hi, Currently the Client for which we are implementing doesn't have PCIDSS regulations, so we are integrating PSP hosted ( Payment Service Provider ) gateway. That means form submit with post data which redirects to Payment Gateway and user put all details of card/banking on payment gateway only and redirecting to success/failure url. So if I submitted the from directly with "ngNoForm" and given API end point of server, then how server will communicate back to Angular about Success/Failure, what exactly I will receive inside component

Answer (score 0):

You should define an API `Post` endpoint that will receive the payment payload response and will redirect to your desired frontend page.

A .NET example would be:

```
[HttpPost("api/payment-done"]
public IActionResult PaymentDone([FromBody] PaymentPayload request)
{
   //do stuff with payload
   return Redirect("http://your-website-page");
}
```